# How to add a resource (*.res) file to the package with components correctly?

Tags: image, delphi, resources, components

I have set of my own Delphi components in the single .dpk file. One of my components needs some images to be distributed with it. I created the RES file (let it be "MyImages.RES"), and I want my visual component to load its content at creation.

How to add this RES file to the DPK correctly?

When I put the {$R 'MyImages.RES'} into my .dpk file, the TResourceStream fails at creation because it can't find my picture by resource name:

```
constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  S := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'MY_PICTURE1', RT_RCDATA);
```

the RES file was created by this RC:

```
MY_PICTURE1 RCDATA "my_picture1.png"
```

Comment: A couple of ideas.  Do you have separate design time and run time packages and the .res is linked only to the design time package?  Or, are you somehow building an exe which isn't using runtime packages?

Comment: @David Heffernan: I have a single package both for designtime and runtime. This components package also is in the same project group with the main project, can this lead to such issues?

Comment: Try adding `ShowMessage(IntToHex(HInstance, 8))` before the call to `TResourceStream.Create`.  If it pops up a dialog with a value of `00400000` then you are linking statically rather than to the package.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Yes, it shows 00400000. Can you give some advice how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `{$R 'MyImages.res'}` directive directly in the unit where your component is declared. When loading the resource, use `FindClassHInstance(TMyComponent)` (module where `TMyComponent` is) instead of `HInstance` (main executable - this might coincidentally also be the module where `TMyComponent` is, depending on how you're linking).

Edit: It seems you want to link with runtime packages but you are in fact linking the component statically into your main executable. Apparently, you have already compiled your runtime (and designtime) .bpl packages. To compile your main project (.exe or .dll) which is using the component with runtime packages, you should:

1. select "Build with runtime packages" in Project Options
2. add the base name of your package to the list of runtime packages in Project Options.

Comment: But when I put {$R 'MyImages.res'} into the implementation section of TMyComponent's module, the main executable can't compile, because of the message "file not found 'MyImages.res'"

Comment: You should make sure the .res file is somewhere where the compiler can find it. Typically, it would be in the same directory as the .dcu.

Comment: Yes, it worked after adding the path to RES file into the main Library path of IDE. Thank you both very much, TOndrej and David!

Comment: note. for c++ buildet you need to use: FindClassHInstance(__classid(TMyComponent))

Answer (score 1):

From the comments to your question it is clear that you are not linking to the package correctly at runtime and `TMyComponent` is being linked statically to your executable rather than being linked dynamically from the package.

You can solve this one of two ways:

1. Fix the linking problems so that you do indeed link to the package at runtime. This is configured in Project | Options | Packages in the Delphi IDE.
2. If you want to link statically then you need to link the .res file to your executable too. @TOndrej's answer gives a neat way to arrange that.

Comment: Which should be an option for a component. I mean the component should be able to load its resource regardless of whether it's linked into a BPL, DLL, or EXE, with or without runtime packages. My answer below handles all cases because the resource will always be linked into the same module where the class is linked into.

Comment: But how to change the type of link? Is it possible when the package is in the same project group with my main executable?

Comment: @Andrew: just use my answer, it should work the same in all cases.

Comment: @TOndrej You are missing the point that @Andrew may well want to have runtime linking.  You are correct that the `$R` declaration should reside in the .pas file that uses the resource. No debate there.

Comment: @Andrew to use runtime packages look in Project | Options | Packages in the IDE.  Make sure "Build with runtime packages" is checked.  Of course, many people, myself included, prefer to use static linking but the choice is yours.

Comment: @David please explain, what am I missing and how?

Comment: @TOndrej Andrew asked how to change the type of link. You responded by saying "just use my answer, it should work the same in all cases". Your answer does not deal with runtime linking at all and so it does not address that issue. Andrew appears to want to use runtime linking but adopting your solution lets him continue with the belief that he is using packages when in fact he isn't. Anyway, I think I've done enough work for this question, especially as you are getting all the rep!!  ;-)

Comment: @David, how does my answer not deal with runtime linking? Do you think the answer is incomplete in some way? Is there an issue? By all means, do point it out, thanks!

Comment: @TOndrej Because Andrew wishes to use runtime linking and doesn't know how to. You don't explain how to. Your answer just explains how to link the .res file in a way that works irrespective of the linking mechanism. But Andrew specifically asked, in the comment prior to your "just use my answer" comment, how to switch to runtime linking of packages.

Comment: "Build with runtime packages" should be checked *and* the package included in the list of runtime packages.

Comment: Thanks guys! :) After reading all these comments I understood how to use packages a little bit more than before (this is a new tool for me).